# How to get a string out of a string in powershell?

Tags: powershell

So im trying to standarize the Naming convention of AD groups, but for that i need to be able to solve the following problem by trying to get a string out of this string.

Hellow_World_Hello

How to get "Hel Wor Hel" out of that string?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you search for it?

Comment: I have tried Substring() but i have a list to work with, my logic is not enough, I need to get the first 3 char of the begining of the word in the string 3 char for the next one and so on the phrase delimiter is a symbol like  "_ - Space", the problem is that is always substring(0,3) for the begining but depending on the phrase for the next word i dont know, i just dont know which way to go in this situation. sorry im new in powershell.

Comment: Try `('Hellow_World_Hello' -split '_' | Foreach-Object { $_.Substring(0,3) }) -join ' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. this should work in your requirement.

```
$str = "Hellow_World_Hello"
$Result = ""
foreach($str1 in $str.split("_")){ $Result = $Result + $str1.SubString(0,3) + " "} 
Write-Host $Result
```

Comment: wow, like a charm! thanks a lot.